# Unable to access the values of a struct in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I am currently learning to code C, but I am stuck at creating a struct on the heap.
I have got the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
} some_struct;

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("%i", sizeof(some_struct));
    some_struct * p_struct = malloc(sizeof(some_struct));
    p_struct->a = 600;
    p_struct->b = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

But when executed Visual Studio tells me:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6286C1E39 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFFAFBE4440.

Also the debugger tells me the memory of both a and b is unable to be read. I understand that the two integers should be uninitialized, but why is their memory seemingly unreadable?

Comment: You should use `%z`, not `%i`, for printing values of type `size_t`. You should also check that `malloc` doesn't return `NULL` to indicate allocation failure. Other than that, the code looks fine.

Comment: Change your warning level to 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your address, it looks like the lack of prototype for `malloc()` is the issue. Do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

The implicit `int` causes the value returned by `malloc()` to be truncated (assuming 64 bit addresses and 32 bit ints).  Hence, thus producing an invalid address.

In pre-C99, if a protoype is not found for a function, compiler implicitly declares a prototype with `int`. But this is no longer valid since C99.

Answer (score 4):

You should `#include <stdlib.h>` which contains `malloc`. Doesn't Visual Studio give you any warnings?

When you don't include `<stdlib.h>`, `malloc` is given an implicit return type of `int`. This *might* work on a platform where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(some_struct*)`, but if they're of different size (e.g. 32 bit ints and 64 bit pointers), the value returned by `malloc` is truncated before assignment.

The value in the error message (`0xFFFFFFFFAFBE4440`) suggests that this is the case: `malloc` returned a pointer with a value of `0x????????AFBE4440`, which was truncated to `0xAFBE4440`, which was sign extended to `0xFFFFFFFFAFBE4440` on assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It is happend because you call the function malloc but you forgot (or you did not know) to include stdlib.h.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
} some_struct;

int main(void) {
    printf("%lu", sizeof(some_struct));
    some_struct * p_struct = malloc(sizeof(some_struct));
    p_struct->a = 600;
    p_struct->b = 100;
    return 0;
}
```

You probably noticed that i changed:

> printf("%i", sizeof(some_struct));

With:

> printf("%lu", sizeof(some_struct));

Becouse if you turn on your compiler settings you will get:

> format ‘%i’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Werror=format=]|

NOTE:
Using %i instead of %d its ok in here but will not be the same with scanf.